# The lowest temperature bound

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

As absolute zero is impossible, what are the most general and lowest bounds to temperature? Are they Universal? Is there a principle behind them?

Comment: Absolute zero is the bound i.e. it is possible to approach arbitrarily close to it.

Comment: Well, arbitrarily close is not enough... If absolute zero is not attainable, then there should be another non-zero bound (think about natural units or the maximal velocity in special relativity).

Comment: @riemannium What is the smallest value of $T$ on the domain $T>0$?

Comment: No, because if you use some non-zero bound it will always (in principle at least) be possible to cool a system to a temperature below your bound, no matter how small you make your non-zero bound. I have to say this seems obvious to me, so I wonder if we are talking at cross purposes.

Comment: Physics is not mathematics...It is physmatics. Physics is about limits, the limit of "zero" or "infinity" should be replaced by finite values (that, of course, does NOT mean you can take the limit zero or infinity if you use the continuum but the real physical world is discrete).

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14538 a paper that may be of interest, a quantum mechanical limit on how quickly you can cool things.  If you were to integrate this forward in time, it would tell you how close to zero (you could by then have feasibly achieved)

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum.  You can always use more clever tricks to get closer to 0.

A quick google search for "closest to absolute zero" yielded [this](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/earth/technologies/biggest_chill.html) as the first link

> The next time you're shivering under your winter coat as your local weather forecaster predicts "record lows," take heart. It could be a lot colder.
>
> Try one-half-billionth of a degree above absolute zero, or about -460 degrees Fahrenheit (-273 degrees Celsius).
>
> That's the lowest temperature ever recorded, recently measured by NASA-funded researchers at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology who used a unique combination of gravitational forces and magnetic fields to cool sodium gas.

That was from back in '03.

Also, when you really start pushing it, there are more exotic answers.  You can actually achieve negative temperatures.  Absolute zero is a well understood limit for systems that are at a stable point, but if you have a system at a metastable point (think of a ball at the top of a nice round hill that could tip off and roll in any direction at any time), it turns out that you can actually create situations whose temperature is negative.  Negative temperatures defy intuition, so don't worry about them too much, but technically they can be made.  The rationale for that comes from the very precise definition of temperature which scientists use, which can act a bit strange in metastable states.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that systems with a negative temperature are hotter than a system with a finite positive temperature in the sense that heat flows from a system with a negative temperature to a system with a finite positive temperature.

Comment: @DavidHammen True.  I was going to just chalk that up as part of the uninuititive bit of those temperatures.  The fact that that is possible doesn't make any sense until you actually dig into the definitions of all the terms.